# iBooks: my ePub doesn't show PNG images, a question mark is in its place instead

Tags: png, epub, ibooks

I'm making by myself an ePub book. In this book I put some screenshot as a PNG image inside an XHTML page. So in the content.opf I referenced the XHTML page...

Until few days ago it worked: the XHTML with PNG image was showed.

Now I see only a blue question mark at the place of the PNG image preview. But if I double tap onto the question mark, the preview correctly shows the PNG image.

This happens in IBooks and Stanza, but not in GoodReader and others eBook readers...

An tips?

------------------ EDITED ------------------------

Every PNG is ~200Kb and its dimension is ~2500x2500 with 300 dpi.

I don't know if thew problem is the dimension or the image format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your images are too big for a start. Apple state that the maximum pixel size of an image on a page is 2 million pixels. So 6.25 million pixels might be a bit of a problem.

Comment: Yes I thought this too, but before the iOS 4.3.3 (so onto iOS 4.3.2) these big size images worked well!

Comment: I think you have been caught by the fact that Apple are now enforcing this both in iBooks and at the upload to the iBookstore end. We had a book rejected last week for being a single pixel too wide for the limit (making it about 2000 pixels too big)

Comment: Nic you are right! I've reduced the size of the images and now all works fine. Now I must only reach the same quality. Can you give me the link where I can find all the limitations for iBooks such that?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for me. It's strange. I have used the same image on page one, it works. Then I use the same image again a few pages later, it no longer works. There's just a small picture displayed with a question mark inside.

I am using `tex4ebook` to generate the ePUB.